# Deep reinforcement learning with multiple "continuous actions"

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Below is a high level diagram of how my Agent should look like in order to be able to interact with a custom gym environment I made.

[image]

#### States and actions

The environment has three states [s1, s2, s3] and six actions [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6]
states and actions can be any value between 0 and 1

#### Question:

Which algorithms are suitable for my problem ? I am aware that there are algorithms that are good at handling continuous action space like (DDPG, PPO, etc.) but I can't see how they might operate when they should output multiple actions at each time-step.
Finally, are there any gym environments that have the described property (multiple actions) and are there any python implementations for solving those particular environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, PPO, DDPG, TRPO, SAC, etc. are indeed suitable for handling continuous action spaces for reinforcement learning problems.
These algorithms will give out a vector of size equal to your action dimension and each element in this vector will be a real number instead of a discrete value. Note that stochastic algorithms like PPO will give a multivariate probability distribution from which you sample the actions.

Most of the robotic environments in [Mujoco-py](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py), [PyBullet](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/tree/master/examples/pybullet), [Robosuite](https://github.com/ARISE-Initiative/robosuite), etc. are environment with multiple continuous action spaces. Here the action spaces can be of the form `[torque_for_joint_1, torque_for_join_2, ..., torque_for_joint_n]` where torque_for_joint_i can be a real valued number determining by how much would that joint move.

Regarding implementations for solving these environments, robosuite does offer sample solutions for benchmarking the environments with different algorithms. You could also look up [stable-baselines](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3) or one of the standard RL libraries.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! I have one other question please, each action in the output vector of actions should be bounded between [0 and 1], meaning that the maximum sum of the six actions will equal to 6 (i.e. if all actions were equal to 1). How can I ensure that each action is indeed bounded between 0 and 1. 
I am aware that there is multi-class classification using softmax activation function, but that's not what I want, because this will bound the sum of all actions between 0 and 1 and not each action separately. 
Thanks

Comment: Does that mean that all the actions are dependent on each other?

Comment: No they are not dependent on each other. In fact they work as if each action comes from a seperate regressor (but with value between 0 and 1)

Comment: You could just use sigmoid or a shifted tanh non-linearity in the final layer to get the outputs in the range [0,1].

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!